# Auto write input fields value to textarea with separator jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few input fields

```
<input type="text" placeholder="name">
<input type="text" placeholder="age">
<input type="text" placeholder="gender">
<input type="text" placeholder="interest">
```

and every time I write on those input fields it should reflect to the textarea and output a format with | or pipe symbol

Example:

```
<textarea>
name|age|gender|interest
</textarea>
```

and when I add another set of fields it writes it on the second line

```
<textarea>
name|age|gender|interest
name|age|gender|interest
name|age|gender|interest
</textarea>
```

Also "Number of Children" quantity needs to adjust automatically based on per line in the text area or how many children.

Here is My fiddle to make it more clearer https://jsfiddle.net/sjgrLcqx/4/

Comment: So If i can understand you want to output something like Francis | 21 | Female and then if there is another set of inputs you want to append it to the next line?

Comment: yes, you are correct @AngelRoma

Answer (score 1):

I did a few things here.

1. I made your HTML string a single variable so that when I changed it I didn't have to do so twice.
2. I added classes to your inputs so that I could figure out which one the user is typing into.
3. I used a few jQuery methods you might not be aware of, like `index()` and `parent()`.
4. I used a few JavaScript functions to iterate through the properties on the `child` object I created to make creating a string from its attributes easier.

Look over the code and let me know if you have any questions. Also, next time, maybe try this yourself, even if you have no idea where to start. Just keep trying stuff until something starts to work. Coding is challenging but that's what's fun about it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

  var childInfoArray = [];

  var formHtml = '<div class="optionBox"><div class="block" style=""><input class="crow fullName" type="text" placeholder="Full name"><input class="crow width50 marginsmall age" type="text" placeholder="Age"><input class="crow width50 nomargin gender" type="text" placeholder="gender"><input class="crow interest" type="text" placeholder="Interest"><span class="remove">Remove this section</span></div><div class="block"><span class="add">Add another child\'s info</span></div></div>';

  jQuery('#frmPaymentSantasgrotto').append(formHtml);

  jQuery('.add').click(function () {
    jQuery('.block:last').before(formHtml);
  });

  jQuery('.optionBox').on('click', '.remove', function () {
    jQuery(this).parent().remove();
  });


  jQuery('.optionBox').on('keyup', 'input', function () {

    var index = $(this).parent().index('div.block');

    var child = {};

    if (childInfoArray[index] != null) {
      child = childInfoArray[index];
    }
    else {
      child = {
        fullName: '',
        age: '',
        gender: '',
        interest: ''
      }
    }

    if ($(this).hasClass('fullName')) {
      child.fullName = jQuery(this).val();
    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass('age')) {
      child.age = jQuery(this).val();
    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass('gender')) {
      child.gender = jQuery(this).val();
    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass('interest')) {
      child.interest = jQuery(this).val();
    }
    childInfoArray[index] = child;
    printChildArray();

  });

  function printChildArray() {
    var childInfoString = "";
    childInfoArray.forEach(child => {
      Object.values(child).forEach((attribute, index) => {
        childInfoString += attribute;
        if (index !== Object.keys(child).length - 1) {
          childInfoString += ' | ';
        }
        else {
          childInfoString += ' \n';
        }
      });
    });
    $('textarea').html(childInfoString);
  }

});
```

Comment: wow, this is cool, two thing is that the "Add another child's info" is duplicating when I add and if I remove a section it does not remove on the textarea part, thanks

Comment: add `childInfoArray = childInfoArray.splice(index, 0); printChildArray();` to the `jQuery('.optionBox').on('click', '.remove', function () {` . It will remove the child that is removed from the array and update the textarea. And if you don't want the "Add another child's info"  to be duplicated, remove it from the `append()` html.

Comment: Hi @Katie.Sun sorry I just could not get it to work, can you supply a fiddle for me, thanks

Comment: hmm you are right it isn't working how I'd expect. will take a look ASAP